# how to create a "Division" function which contains variable number of parameters in Java

Tags: java, methods

I want to ask a question how to create a "Division" function which contains variable number of parameters in Java? Just Like As I did for sum method:

```
    public static int sum(int ... x)
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(int i : x)
        {
            sum=sum+i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: well, what is that method supposed to do? why does the exactly same way not work for division? Are you running into integer division (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)?

Comment: explain, and give maybe an example

Comment: can you share a sample input and the result you'd like to get for that input?

Comment: What would you expect `div(5, 6, 7, 8)` to return? `sum(5, 6, 7, 8)` is obvious (26). Even `mult(5, 6, 7, 8)` is obvious (1680). But `div(5, 6, 7, 8)`? Is that `5 / 6 / 7 / 8`, i.e. `5 / (6 * 7 * 8) = 5 / 336 = 0.01488`?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a div function which will help you to print digits after decimal till the max value of int (you can change it to long in the loop if you want) just use the div() function The format of parameters is Dividend, Divisor,The no of digits after decimal you want

```
import java.util.*;   
public class Divisor {
public static void div(int a, int  b,int n){    
int q=(int) a/b;
System.out.print(q+".");
int r=a%b;

    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
                   
        if(r!=0)
        {
          if(r<b)
           r=r*10;
      if(r%b!=0)
      { 
      System.out.print((int)r/b);
      r=r%b;          
       
      }        
     else
     {
      System.out.print(r/b);
      break;
  }       
        }
       else
       {
        r=r/b;
        System.out.print(r);
        break;
        }}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, the difference is that you're gonna have to provide a number to divide as parameter:

```
public static int div(int div, int ... x)
{
   for(int i : x)
   {
      if(i > 0) div=div/i;
   }
   return div;
 }
```

Be careful to test if **i** is greater than 0, otherwise the compiler will throw an error, since you cannot divide by 0.

Comment: Silently ignoring zero divisors is bad. Let it throw division-by-zero exception. Even if you truly want to ignore zeroes, why prevent division by negative numbers?

Comment: The op did not specify clearly what he wants, so every assumption is valid. He could want to ignore, or not, we don't know. What I can do is just warn about the division, so he can make something he wants about it.